# Cannot normalize attribute "timezone" because injected serializer is not a normalizer

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, object

Can't normalize DateTime onject in php (Symfony)... Why it doesn't work? DateTime is the object, isn't it?
$normalizers->normalize($patient->getDateAdded())
Error:
Cannot normalize attribute "timezone" because injected serializer is not a normalizer

Answer (score 2):

You must inject serializer into normalizer. Use $normalizer->setSerializer($this->get('))

Answer (score 0):

Try this way `$patient->getDateAdded()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: if  i need to normalize not only dateTime object, what to do? Object can exisits in parent object, and child objects can be a lot in parent... (

Comment: I think you need to consult official Symfony documentation `http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html`